# Can jQuery detect when user resizes browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote simple code with jQuery that hides navbar when user scrolls the page. I works great, but now I want add one more thing.

I want it to work like it does now when user viewport width is more than 768px.
But when user viewport is smaller then 768px I want that navbar to be visible all the time.

The code should be smart enough, that it can detect browser was resized by user and it should still work.

**To sum up:**

1. User start my page with chrome viewport 1024px - when he scrolls page down navbar is hiding, when he goes back to the top of the page navbar is reappearing.
2. Then user resizes chrome and has viewport 700px - when he scrolls page down navbar should be always on.

Any smart ideas how to achieve it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".navbar").show();
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {     
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $(".navbar").fadeOut();
      } else {
        $(".navbar").fadeIn();
      }     
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Firstly note that you've got nested document.ready event handlers which is a little redundant. To fix your issue you can hook to the `resize` event of the `window`, like this: `$(window).on('resize', fn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be solve by using `$(window).resize`. Here is the full demo how it is done. Hope this answer yours.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function() {
      winWidth = $(window).width();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if (winWidth <= 700) {
        $(".navbar").css({
          position: "fixed",
          width: "100%"
        });
        $("p").css("margin-top","60px");
      } else {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
          $(".navbar").fadeOut();
        } else {
          $(".navbar").fadeIn();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <p>
    The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
    architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia
    dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid
    ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914 translation by H. Rackham "But I must explain to
    you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
    rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires
    to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain
    some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It behaves just the way I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

edited: actually, you would want the following, previous answer (window.width) only checks when you tell it this will whenever resized.

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();  // if you need var outside of function for something

$(window).resize(function() {
    windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize > 700) {
    dowhatever();
  });
 } 
});
```